# React Native: How to go about using ShouldComponentUpdate with setInterval and setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval, setstate

I am using a combination of `setInterval`, located in my `componentDidMount` function, which fetches data from an API and sets a state to the fetched data, that I display on my react-native-maps. The problem is that using `setInterval` with `setState` is too costly, since the map has to re-render every 5 seconds.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        api.getData().then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                data: res
            })
        });
    }, 5000);
}
```

I have researched this, finding that I should use `houldComponentUpdate`, but I am not able to get it to work, as the map does not render correctly, rendering when its not supposed to and not rendering when its supposed to.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
        if(this.state.data[i].value !== nextState.data[i].value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am comparing the states of data that I have with the next state's data, `i.e this.state.data !== nextState.data`, and I return true if so.

Am I going about this correctly, such that this is an issue that ShouldComponentUpdate should solve, and I am just not writing that function correctly, or should I be focusing on a different solution?

Comment: What's inside of your data?

Comment: @FisNAN The data is an object that contains an integer "value" property and an integer "time" property

Comment: The answer also depends on the `props` and another `state` of your component. I posted an answer, it might not work exactly for your case, but you should got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The flew in `shouldComponentUpdate` is that:

- You also stops rerender when component receives new `props`
- If `nextState` has different length, your method doesn't check it. In this case we always want to rerender

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  // Just an example, you need compare actual parameter which inside props
  if (this.props !== nextProps) { 
    return true;
  }
  
  if (this.state.data.length !== nextState.data.length) {
    return true;
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
    if (this.state.data[i].value !== nextState.data[i].value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am new to ReactNative, so could you explain what comparing this.props and nextProps does, and why we need it?

Comment: You don't want to stop the rerender when component receives new `props` in most of cases. But I didn't see your component. Does it receive any props?

Comment: Yes, it does. It receives various props such as searchbar suggestions, selected searchbar item, etc.

Comment: @ZainBudhwani then you need to check every key inside `this.props`

Comment: So like this.props.suggestions !== nextProps.suggestions? Thanks, makes sense now!

Comment: @ZainBudhwani Yes. `Object.keys()` can be used to compare all props, or you can pick some `props` which make sense to you when rerender is required.